# Searching through JSON objects with input from HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-input

I have a JSON file which I get using jQuery.

I would like to know how to search through the items and only get the items related to the HTML input.

This is what I tried:

```
 function Search(form) {

        $(".products").empty();
        $.getJSON('products.json', function(data) {
            $(data.Products).each(function(index, item) {
                if(form == item.Name) {

                    var input = document.getElementById('searchForm');

                    $('<div/>', {'class':'productname'}).text(item.Name).append(
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Album: '+item.Album}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails'}).append($('<img>').attr({src:item.Source,title:item.Name,alt:item.Name,class:'productimage'})),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Genre: '+item.Genre}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Price: '+item.Price}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Quantity: '+item.Quantity}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Tracks: '+item.Tracks}),
                            $('<div/>').append(
                                    $('<button />', {'class':'productbutton'})
                                            .text('Add To Cart.')
                                            .click(function(){
                                                $.fn.SaveToCart(i,item.Name, item.Album, item.Price);
                                            })
                            )
                    ).appendTo(".products");
                }   else if (form == item.Album) {

                    var input = document.getElementById('searchForm');

                    $('<div/>', {'class':'productname'}).text(item.Name).append(
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Album: '+item.Album}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails'}).append($('<img>').attr({src:item.Source,title:item.Name,alt:item.Name,class:'productimage'})),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Genre: '+item.Genre}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Price: '+item.Price}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Quantity: '+item.Quantity}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Tracks: '+item.Tracks}),
                            $('<div/>').append(
                                    $('<button />', {'class':'productbutton'})
                                            .text('Add To Cart.')
                                            .click(function(){
                                                $.fn.SaveToCart(i,item.Name, item.Album, item.Price);
                                            })
                            )
                    ).appendTo(".products");



                }
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Search(this);
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
   <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" >
<input name="productname" id="productname" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

Trying this code only refreshes the page.

Any idea on how I can fix it?

Comment: You don't prevent the default form submission behavior

Comment: Perhaps you can work with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727316/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-string/11728751#11728751

Comment: @TimVermaelen Hi, I already got a 'categories' function to work. What I need is to view JSON data based on the user input in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the form from being submitted. You can either just add `return false;` at the very bottom of the `Search()` function (before the last `};`), or remove the inline `onsubmit` and attach a `submit` handler to the form  using jQuery, which will allow you to use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    Search(this);
  });
});
```

Also, you have a spelling error in the following line:

`var input = document.getElementById('searhForm');`

Should be

`var input = document.getElementById('searchForm');`

Comment: (I added `return false;` and fixed the the spelling mistake, however nothing happens.)

Comment: Inside of your `<script></script>` tags

Comment: You'll have to start debugging it - check your console, make sure the ajax request is being sent, validate the data coming back etc.

Comment: Yes I know it's in the script tag, but would I have to remove the code I already did or use it conjunction with ?

Comment: You don't have to remove any code. If you're using the latter example (the jQuery one), just remove the inline `onsubmit` from your form element

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but nothing happens when I click the 'Search' Button. I updated the question with the new code.